# How to push values in array using message hook

Tags: reactjs

I want ta add the state values in array. i also try to use foreach but it gives errors
i want to add values in array whose value is true

```
const [values, setValues] = React.useState({
    rb: true,
    metal: true,
    country: false,
    international: false,
    other: false,
  });
```

expected output is array["rb","meatal"]
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the list of keys into an array using `Object.keys(values)` and then filter it based on the value of the key.

```
Object.keys(values).filter(key => values[key])
```

this will give you the keys that are true in an array.